# Disable the hover effect of a toolstrip in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, hover, toolstrip

I have created an icon based navigation in my C# application.
I have used a toolstrip to do so but I want to get rid of the hover effect.
I can't seem to find anything in the properties or the code and I'm using winforms

Thanks in advance

Comment: To which "hover effect" do you refer?  The colorization changes, the pop-up tooltip, ...?

Comment: The light blue backlight that appears

Comment: That will not be trivial.  Explore `ToolStripRenderer`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229720(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score -1):

toolStrip1.ShowItemtoolTips = false;

Comment: You are presuming to know to which effect(s) OP is referring.